# Ember Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I keep hitting this error and am pretty stumped as to why. I can't trace the error in dev tools back to anything in my primary JS file.  My Ember-related code is as follow:

```
  var App = Ember.Application.create();
  App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bMRERKrXfS';
      return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
        model = {
          list1: data
        };
        return model;
      });
    }
  });

  Ember.Handlebars.helper('autocomplete', Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'controls/autocomplete',

    filteredList: function() {
      ...
      }

      return list.filter(function(item) {
        ...
      });
    }.property('list.@each', 'filter')
  }));
```

I have removed app-specific code from the structure there. Any time I try to run this I get the following error:

**Ember Cannot read property 'path' of undefined** which looks to be coming from my ember.min.js file. Any help tracking this down would be great.

[Codepen Demo Link](http://codepen.io/Yuschick/pen/RrbzdO?editors=001)

**EDIT**
When running this code locally and not in CodePen I end up with the following errors:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined** which looks to be thrown by Ember.View.extend

and

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isHelperFactory' of undefined** which is coming from the ember.min file.

**EDIT 2**
I have tried updating the helper to an Ember component:

```
App.AutoCompleteComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  filteredList: function() {
        var list = this.get('list'),
            filter = this.get('filter'),
            filterArr = [],
            filterArrLength;

        if (filter && filter.indexOf(', ') !== -1) {
            filterArr = filter.split(', ');
            filterArrLength = filterArr.length;
            filter = filterArr[filterArrLength - 1]
        }

        if (!filter || (filterArrLength > 0 && filterArr[filterArrLength - 1].length == 0)) {
            $("#filter-results").hide();
            INPUT.unbindKeys();
            return;
        } else {
            if (!$("#filter-results").is(":visible")) {
                INPUT.bindKeys();
                $("#filter-results").show();
            }
        }

        return list.filter(function(item) {
            if (!filterArrLength) {
                return item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter);
            } else {
                return item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterArr[filterArrLength - 1]);
            }
        });
    }.property('list.@each', 'filter')
});
```

And I have updated my Handlebars template to be `"components/auto-complete"`

Still, with this I am receiving the same errors. My CodePen link has also been updated for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.View` is [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html).  See the new docs about writing [helpers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/writing-helpers/).

However based on the functionality described and because you are providing a template I suspect that what you want is a [component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html):

```
// app/components/auto-complete.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({ 
    filteredList: ...
});
```

The template is automatically found by Ember, in this case at `templates/components/auto-complete.hbs`.

Edit to your Edit 2:  Note that defining objects on `App` is now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, @andorov. I guess I am still uncertain about how to update this even after looking through the helpers and components. Should I start with a helper but extend the component instead of the view? I'm still trying to wrap my head around Ember.

Comment: Don't use a helper here at all - they are for DRYing up template logic (no more Views).  Create a component - [here](http://www.programwitherik.com/ember-js-components-examples/) is a longer tutorial about them.

Comment: Thanks! I am still working on getting this written but this is clearly what needs to be done so this I am marking this as my answer. Just need to figure out how to write this now.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Which version of Ember are you using?  Your code appears to be from an older version